# asp.net masterpage & site navigation error

Tags: asp.net

[image: sourcecode1][image: error]

I got above error message. What have I done wrong and how do I fix my code?

Thanks,

[image: sourcecode2]

Comment: Please show us your source code.

Comment: You should put the aspx source code in there as well(or part of it), that should provide for a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your siteMapDataSource control is either not defined or it has a different ID. You should put the aspx source code in there as well(or part of it), that should provide for a more detailed answer.